# jQuery pulsate div

Tags: jquery, html, css

does anyone know what it is that i'm doing wrong?

I'm trying to have the "minus.png" on click, it'll delete the DIV, however if you click the div text, it deletes the div.

I don't want to be able to click the div and delete it on pulsate, I want to be able to click the minus png image, and it deletes it, would you happen to know what it is that I'm doing wrong?

I'm sure it's a simple fix, but it's bugging me badly haha!

Thanks!

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {

      $(".pane").click(function () {
      $(this).effect("pulsate", { times:2 }, 0000).fadeOut('slow').parents(".pane");
});

  });
  </script>

  <div class="pane">
 <a href=""><img align="right" src="http://uploadir.com/u/6hmr4fr1" alt="delete" class="delete" /></a>  
  Simple jQuery script I'm learning to work with, you mad bro?
  </div>

  <div class="pane">
  <a href=""><img align="right" src="http://uploadir.com/u/6hmr4fr1" alt="delete" class="delete" /></a>  
  Simple jQuery script I'm learning to work with, you mad bro?
  </div>

  <div class="pane">
  <a href=""><img align="right" src="http://uploadir.com/u/6hmr4fr1" alt="delete" class="delete" /></a>  
 Simple jQuery script I'm learning to work with, you mad bro?
  </div>

  <div class="pane">
  <a href=""><img align="right" src="http://uploadir.com/u/6hmr4fr1" alt="delete" class="delete" /></a>  
  Simple jQuery script I'm learning to work with, you mad bro?
  </div>
```

FULL code is here:

http://jsfiddle.net/CgPJv/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe `$(".pane")` -> `$(".pane > a")`

http://jsfiddle.net/CgPJv/6/

You're binding clicks on the whole div, instead bind them on the **a** element just like you said

```
$(".pane > a").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().effect("pulsate", { times:2 }).fadeOut('slow');
});
```

Answer (score 4):

**[Code Example](http://jsfiddle.net/CgPJv/11/)**

```
$('.pane a').click(function () {
    $(this).closest('.pane').effect('pulsate', { times:2 }, 0000).fadeOut('slow');
    return false;
});
```

You should also give the `a` tag `href` value. Keeping it empty is against the standards. You can use `href="#"`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to attach the click event to the `img` element, then with `closest()` bubble up to find its `.pane` and fade it out, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $(".pane img").click(function (e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         $(this).closest('.pane').effect("pulsate", { times:2 }, 0000).fadeOut('slow');
      });
});
```

See working [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gnel/CgPJv/16/)

Answer (score 3):

You could attach the click event to the actual image,

```
$(".pane > a > img").on('click...
```

Or you could go directly for the `alt` attribute of the image element -

```
$(".pane img[alt='delete']").on('click...
```

I always like to be as verbose as possible with my selectors as I find it improves readability and makes debugging that much quicker.

In both cases, to get the element you want to actually fade out, you would use the `closest()` function.

```
$(".pane img[alt='delete']").on('click',function () {
  var paneElement = $(this).closest('.pane');
  paneElement.effect("pulsate", { times:2 }, 0000).fadeOut('slow');
  return false;
});
```

Finally, I'm not too sure what you were trying to do with `.parents(".pane")`. It was at the end of the command and didn't really have any effect at all. You can leave it out.

Answer (score 1):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/CgPJv/19/)** — How about a neat little `slideUp()` animation to keep with the style?

Comment: I love you man, thank you for that, I've actually like the much cleaner way to slide.. THANKS MAN!